# After pressing Alt + Tab New Window appear but New Window dosen't get focus

Tags: shortcut-keys, launcher, 15.10

After pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, to change focus, the new window appears but the new window doesn't get the focus. No arrow on the right of the icon in the launcher, no name of the app in the top-left corner, no cursor active, but I see the correct window and the previous one is in the background.

But, if I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the new window get focus.

This started happening a few hours ago. I was changing some key-bindings in system settings.
My current Ubuntu version is 15.10
Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10 is dead (unsupported) for a couple of years now, you need to use a supported version.

Comment: After experimenting and googling finally I found the problem. By mistake, I assigned Alt + Tab to HUD .So that's why switcher was behaving abnormally. Now, Everything is back to normal. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i know where you are coming from. I myself faced the same situation some time ago, windows and its shortcuts...

So to do what you want, you'll have to change the global key binding in Ubuntu. To do that you go to system settings, global shortcuts, then change the keybinding for the "Walk Through Windows" function to the key combo that you like. Maybe Alt+Tab..

Comment: I can't find "Walk Through Windows" function in system settings. But, there is "key to show HUD" function in keyboard shortcuts which is set to Alt + Tab.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the setting you are looking for is in
System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts (Tab) -> Navigation (on left pane)

Look for "Switch windows of an app directly".

Select that and press ALT+TAB.

You will get a warning about it already being assigned. Press "Reassign".

After doing this, I found that ALT+TAB still brings up the window switching HUD window, but most importantly it also changes the focus as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

go to gnome-tweaks > Windows > set the Window Focus to "Focus on Hover"